# log4net won't write to the visual web developer console

Tags: console, log4net, appender

this is my config for log4net but it wont write to the console
**see appender: ConsoleAppender**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>


  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
       type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="C:\Users\name\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\logs\logfile.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">

        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p  %C %m%n%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">

        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p  %C %m%n%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Why doesn't it write to the console?

**Edit 1**
This is how I initialize it:

```cs
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ExecutionEngine\\Libraries\\App.Config"));
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you initializing nhibernate?  Assembly level attribute?  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() ?  Have you tried enabling the log4net debugging flag?

Comment: @ColeW - (1).I am not using Nhibernate, (2)as you can see `<level value="ALL" />` (3)see my edit (4)please explain, thanks for your help

Comment: Haha.  I meant how are you intializing log4net.  Had NHibernate on the brain.

Comment: Is it writing to your log file?  (4) <log4net debug="true">

Comment: @ColeW - yes, but I want both, I want `log.Debug`,`log.Error`,`log.Info` to be written to the console and to the file (for debugging time in production ill have file only) thanks

Comment: @ColeW solved - thank you anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [trace appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TraceAppender.html) for this purpose. For instance like this:

```xml
<appender name="TraceAppender"
          type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <conversionPattern value="%-6level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```